# Allocate class based on school ranking

Tags: excel, sorting

In Excel I am trying to allocate classes to pupils based on their ranking in school. The set of data I have looks like this:

```
S/N    Name    LevelPosition
1    Andrea      10
2    Bryan       25
3    Catty        5
4    Debbie      26 
5    Ellie       30
6    Freddie     28
```

I would like to have a formula that could sort the pupils based on the LevelPosition and allocate the class in order of this sequence - A,B,C,C,B,A. Hence the result would be:

```
S/N    Name    LevelPosition   AllocatedClass
3    Catty        5               A
1    Andrea      10               B  
2    Bryan       25               C 
4    Debbie      26               C 
6    Freddie     28               B 
5    Ellie       30               A
```

Comment: i have 200+ students. The allocation of class will repeat from A to C and back from C to A. Cycle repeats. Yes, you are right, there will be some incidences of pupils with same LevelPosition. we do this allocation in school every year manually by copying and pasting. hence i need something that could facilitate this process of sorting and allocating.

Comment: thanks! currently i have to manually sort levelposition. is it possible to have  a formula to sort and choose too? like temporarily having a sorted table before allocating

Comment: is using macro the only way? the structure of the data i work with every year may vary

Comment: You could use the RANK function to avoid sorting if it would help, with a correction for any ties. I could post an answer to show you what I mean but it needs helper columns inserting.

Answer (score 0):

This was the sort of thing I had in mind.

Column D is just a ranking from bottom to top:-

```
=RANK(C2,C$2:C$7,1)
```

Colum D is adjusted for any ties:-

```
=D2+COUNTIF(D$1:D1,D2)
```

Column E is based on the @pnuts formula:-

```
=CHOOSE(MOD(E2-1,6)+1,"A","B","C","C","B","A")
```

[image]

I've put some ties in to show what would happen. The last two students' allocations are reversed because the second to last has the higher mark.